# How to create a custom sized virtual desktop?

Tags: screenshot, virtual-desktop, high-resolution

Is it possible to create a custom sized virtual desktop (larger than our resolution) so that we could scroll around and pan (so that it acts like a magnifying glass)?
Then it would be possible to maximize the firefox browser to fill up the virtual desktop space and take the screenshot of that window.

I am trying to download the map ([strava heat map](http://labs.strava.com/heatmap/#9/-111.96262/33.74493/blue/bike)) for Arizona, as image file.

Is there any solution regarding this?

First Edit:

I used the

```
xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 800x600 --scale 2.0x2.0 --panning 1600x1200
```

But could not get the full out of it. The browsers does not go full screen. 
I could not post the image as I am new. So, desktop has increased the size but browser could not be maximized to fill desktop.

Comment: Yes, in Linux, using `xrandr`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I did what you suggested (mentioned in fist edit above). I used the xrandr command, but could not make the browser to go full screen. And, is it possible in mac too ?

Comment: I don't use your extra parameters. My string is `xrandr --output LVDS1 --panning {width}x{height}`, where `LVDS1` was identified as the primary device on running `xrandr` without parameters. I have just tested UHD4K (3840x2160) and it works fine on Ubuntu. I kept the terminal open so I could reset to standard resolution (in my case 1366x768). Firefox fills the whole space when I press <kbd>F11</kbd>. I use this with screen capture in order to capture a whole web page which is scrolled in standard resolution (similar to your problem). I have no idea if it works on a Mac: you'll have to try it.

Comment: @AFH I used                                                                                       xrandr --output LVDS1 --panning {3840}x{2160}                                  But I received following as an error
xrandr: --panning: invalid argument '{3840}x{2160}'
Try 'xrandr --help' for more information.               Is there anything that I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, I was using `{}` to indicate a description, rather than a literal string! it should be `xrandr --output LVDS1 --panning 3840x2160`

Answer (score 0):

Just as there's many ways to kick a dwarf, there's several ways to smoosh a screenshot of this strava heat map you so covet.

With regards to the xrandr route, xrandr allows a display size up to 10,000 x 10,000. Rather than doubling the scale, simply keep the scale the same and enlarge the display size. The browser will, or at least *should* stretch out and the off-screen content will continue to render. Then it's a matter of taking a screenshot of the entire desktop.

A shell script like this might do you well:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --panning 9000x9000 --scale 1.0x1.0

# allow time for content to download
sleep 200

# take your screenshot
scrot --quality 100 'screenshot.tiff'

# return to original display settings
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --panning 1920x1080 --scale 1.0x1.0
```

General tips: Once the display has enlarged, it's quite hard to navigate and arrange the zoom level etc. It's best to have the zoom level preset before modifying the display. Enlarging the display is resource intensive, so it may take some trial and error to determine the best size before your system spaz's out totally. Also, to improve your chances, it's best to run your browser instance with all addons disabled e.g. firefox --safe-mode